# Font awesome icon font as a placeholder in input after adding class with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, input, font-awesome, placeholder

I am trying to use font-awesome icons as a placeholder in search input field.

[Jsfiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/831/)

I use corresponding html entity as a placeholder, then use pseudo class to style placeholder with correct font-family (example 2 in jsfiddle):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="icon" type="text" placeholder="&#61442;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    font-family:'arial', sans-serif;
}
input.icon {
    padding:5px;
}
input.icon::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
input.icon::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
input.icon::-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

It works as expected.

The problem starts when I try to add input class and placeholder via jquery (example 1 in jsfiddle):

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wrapper input:first').addClass('icon');
$('.wrapper input:first').attr("placeholder", "&#61442;");
});
```

It doesn't apply font-family to input placeholder and just shows entity text instead.

I tried to mix things around and finally giving up. Please help!

[Jsfiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/831/)

P.S.:
The rout of adding `:before` with font `content` to input wrapper in css will not work for my particular case.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes tried before and just tried again - and it didn't work for me. In case I am doing it wrong, If you can update jsfiddle with correct change of order that solves the problem, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should parse the hash first. You can use `$.parseHTML`:

```
$('.wrapper input:first').attr("placeholder", $.parseHTML("&#61442;")[0].data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.wrapper input:first').attr("placeholder", $('<textarea />').html("&#61442;").html());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rx/833/)

This works by passing the value as HTML instead of text, which can be achieved by creating a reference to an element which doesn't really exist.