# Is it possible to add a pseudo after selector to the placeholder of an input

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a font-awesome icon to the end of a placeholder text, I know that [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842889/font-awesome-icon-font-as-a-placeholder-in-input-after-adding-class-with-jquery) works, but it lead me to wonder whether adding Font awesome content code via the css will work.

Is something like this possible:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder::after
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, no luck, looking for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

`input::-webkit-input-placeholder::after` is not valid, because `input` does not have inner content - there is no `:before` and `:after`.

You can't select pseudo-element of pseudo-element. So `input:placeholder:after` will select `:after` of `input`

Comment: so is there any alternative way to add something after the placeholder of an input

Comment: @Jeevan Nop. But try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842889/font-awesome-icon-font-as-a-placeholder-in-input-after-adding-class-with-jquery